# [website] and [websites] tags

Tags: discussion, tags

It looks like, apart from one migrated question, that [website](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website) is being used to refer to the Android Market website.  It should be renamed to [market-website](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/market-website) or something if we want to keep it.  We could possibly just edit them to use the existing [market](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/market) tag instead.

[websites](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/websites) has two about the browser (those should probably be retagged [browser](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser)), one actually about websites, and one about viewing web pages offline.  The [html](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html) tag is similarly all over the place, I'm not sure how we should sort that out.

Thoughts?

Comment: the existing [market] tag is definitely preferable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ugh.

I don't see anything for it but to manually re-tag. Fortunately there aren't that many.

***Update***: I cleaned up [website](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website) and [websites](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/websites). [html](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html) looks a bit more tricky.